# RoR application request parameters getting overwritten with random symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I have an application running Ruby 2.7.6 and Rails 6.1. Also using rom and rom-http for API calls. We have suddenly started to see our URLs in the browser, as well as server side API request parameters get overwritten with one of the symbols we use to represent an ID in the code. For example a request that should be https://sampleapi.json?currency=USD&locale=EN will be turned into https://sampleapi.json?currency=%3Asearch_id&locale=EN.

`:search_id` is a symbol we do use as a request parameter in many other places where we send a unique id related to a user search. But somehow, it has been injecting itself into almost all API calls as the actual value (encoded as %3Asearch_id). Sometimes we see API calls filled with almost every request parameter set this way.

The suspect is that something in activeresource or one of the rom gems has changed at some point and we never accounted for it.

There are some requests that would have &search_id as a request parameter... but with this bug the symbol :search_id itself is getting into the right side of param values.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Request handler code that processes data to form the final request:

```
def call(dataset)
      uri = URI(dataset.uri)

      uri.path += [dataset.name, dataset.path.presence].compact.join('/') + '.json'
      # recaptcha api endpoint urls
      Rails.logger.info "api endpoint is #{dataset.name}"
      if (dataset.name == '/hotels/rooms' && Settings.enable_recaptcha)
        api_path = dataset.name.split('/')
        uri = URI(Settings.recaptcha_api_gateway_url)
        uri.path += ['/', api_path.last, dataset.path.presence].compact.join('/')
      end
      
      if Rails.env == 'test' && dataset.name == '/hotels/rateshopping'
        dataset.params[:client_ip] = "74.125.228.110"
      end

      if dataset.request_method == :get
        uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(dataset.params.symbolize_keys.to_a.sort)
      else
        uri.query = "ip_address=#{$user_ip}"
      end

      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

      http.use_ssl = uri.scheme.to_s == 'https'

      request_klass = Net::HTTP.const_get(ROM::Inflector.classify(dataset.request_method))

      Rails.logger.info "dataset.params: #{dataset.params}"
      request = request_klass.new(uri.request_uri)

      dataset.headers.each_with_object(request) do |(header, value), request|
         request[header.to_s] = value
      end

      if dataset.request_method == :post
        request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        request.body = dataset.params.to_json
      end

      with_cache(dataset, uri) do
        with_logging(dataset, uri) { http.request(request) }
      end
    end
```

Comment: Can you show the code that generated this URL?

Comment: Well its sort of an over complicated series of events. There is some code from rom that maps certain attributes to the request object, and then eventually goes to activeresource to generate the request itself and map it to the plain Ruby object.

Comment: I mean specifically where this URL is generated, not whatever ceremony is involved in getting to that point. It's important we have some code to reproduce the problem, otherwise we're just guessing. Do include any code examples as an edit to the question. In comments it's much harder to read.

Comment: True. Ok let me grab the most helpful portion and share

Comment: I added the final RequestHandler.rb code. This is the final place where data is compiled

Comment: It does seem odd you're having to use `URI.encode_www_form` directly vs., say, `link_to`, which Rails does provide. I'd suspect `symbolize_keys` is the problem here, where you might mean `stringify_keys`.

Comment: It's also very odd seeing a global like `$user_ip` as well, as Rails does have multiple requests going on at the same time.

Comment: If it helps at all.. this code is quite old and has not been changed. We started to see this issue very rarely when we did an upgrade from ruby 2.4 to 2.7 and rails from 5 to 6. Of course a ton of gems also changed as well. We saw this issue sporadically at that point... but after a server restart last week (with no code change) the occurrences have skyrocketed. Unfortunately we have not been able to reproduce it reliably. The one interesting thing is that it totally clears when the server restarts and comes back after some unknown action occurs

Comment: Something that might've been done as a matter of convenience before could have been removed in the interest of "correctness". I'm just pointing out possible root causes.

Comment: It seems as though once this value gets its way into requests... it is there permanently for all users until the webserver restarts. Then it can be fine for quite a while.. until it starts and does not stop